# Django serialize POST & PUT request in a nested object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm using the [Writable Nested Serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) to serialize my request. I had no problem serializing doing PUT/POST when the data is nested in 1 layer.

(i.e. `{name:'personA', project:{ name:'projA', client:'clientA'}}`)

However, I ran into a problem when it is nested in 2 layers - I couldn't figure out on how to modify the `update()` function. Please help!

**data sample**

```
{
    "id": 6106,
    "name": {
        "id": 213,
        "name": "personA"
    },
    "project": {
        "id": 1663,
        "project": "ProjectA",
        "client": {
            "id": 72,
            "name": "ClientA"
        },
        "project_manager": {
            "id": 32,
            "name": "personB"
        }
    },
    "booking": 100,
    "date": "2017-12-01"
}
```

**serializers.py**

```
class projectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    client = clientSerializer()
    project_manager = userSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = project
        fields = ('id', 'project', 'client', 'project_manager')

class bookingListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    project = projectSerializer()
    name = userSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = bookingList
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'project', 'booking', 'date')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        project_data = validated_data.pop('project')
        name_data = validated_data.pop('name')
        try:
            project_instance = project.objects.filter(**project_data)[0]
            name_instance = user.objects.filter(**name_data)[0]
        except IndexError:
            raise serializers.ValidationError
        # update the project if request is valid
        instance.project = project_instance
        instance.name = name_instance
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

**views.py**

```
# other viewsets...
class bookingListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = bookingList.objects.all()
    serializer_class = bookingListSerializer
```